# TEST ECX, 3 isn't testing the value pointed to by ECX

Tags: testing, assembly, x86, ollydbg

I have this:

```
TEST ECX, 3
```

`ECX` contains the address memory which contains the character `'a'`.

But, after the test, ZF is set to 1! How is this possible?

Here are the screenshots [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPTMu.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPTMu.png) the instruction.

Comment: Where exactly is the indication for ZF being set in the "after" image?

Comment: `0xc and 0x3 = 0x00`, so I don't know why you perceive that as strange.

Comment: How is this possible? Simple. The `test` instruction functions the same as the `and` instruction, with one small difference - the destination is never updated. So, as `cad` says, you've got 0x42AA8C & 0x3 or 10001100 & 00000011 if we look at the lower 8 bits.

Comment: Maybe you wanted `test [ecx], 3`

Comment: @Jester Just interested: why do you think so? BTW, I think you're missing a `PTR` directive.

Comment: @cad  I think so because he specified that the memory contains character `'a'` and that's only relevant if he wanted to access it. Also, `'a'` is 97 which would indeed result in `ZF=0` as expected. PS: Not all assemblers use `PTR`.

Comment: @Jester OK. Regarding `PTR`, how does the assembler know then how much data the instruction operates on? Does the immediate operand imply this?

Comment: There may be some default, but for example nasm uses size specifiers but not the `PTR` keyword, so in nasm that would be `test byte [ecx], 3` for example. In this case the size doesn't matter though, since we only check the low 2 bits and that works the same for byte, word, dword, qword :)

Comment: @Jester Yes, OK, I meant `PTR` and similar because otherwise you could probably just as well argue that AT&T syntax doesn't use `PTR` (well, it doesn't but it implements the same concept with instruction suffixes). "In this case the size doesn't matter though" Holy crap, despite the non-negligible time I've spent writing x86 Assembly code I was not aware of that! Thanks for clearing that up. :)

Comment: @cad and Jester: the size still matters if the address is the last byte of a page, and the next page is unmapped.  A byte memory operand will work; a larger memory operand will do a load that crosses into the next page and faults.  I think the ISA requires a CPU to do an access check on the next page and fault on a wider load, even if the specific microarch optimized by finding the highest set bit in one operand and not actually doing the load from the other side of a cache or page line split if the value wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

ZF indicates if the result of the last instruction was zero. Your code line effectively sets the flags, including ZF, according to the result of

```
0x42AA8C AND 0x03
```

which is `0x00` because `0b1100 AND 0b0011 = 0x00`.
Therefore, the zero flag is set.

For further information on `TEST` and other x86 instructions, look [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_315.html).

Answer (score 0):

You used the `TEST` instruction with a register operand, thus the content of the register is tested. To test a memory location, use a memory operand:

```
TEST DWORD PTR [ECX], 3
```